# Compile Twitter4j with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, twitter4j

I'm trying to use the `twitter4j` library. And I saw on their website that you can use Maven to integrate it.

So In my gradle.build file I did

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
jcenter()
}
```

and compile:

```
project(":core") {
apply plugin: "java"


dependencies {
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.3'
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to do the trick. I can't use any of the classes from `twitter4j` even after cleaning and refreshing everything. What I'm concerned about is that I downloaded the `twitter4j-4.0.3.zip` and extracted it , but I never placed the folder or it's content anywhere? Feels like i'm missing something?

Comment: How about you be more specific?  Show us your exact build file, and exactly what's happening that shouldn't be happening. The build script should be called "build.gradle".  it seems like you have a multiproject build. What is your directory structure?

Comment: I put it in a pastebin since the format was messed up when I was trying to edit, http://pastebin.com/Ke1VL63j. I use libgdx framework so the structure splits into IOS, android ,core etc..

Comment: SO's "code sample" format is awkward, so I can understand that. By providing this in pastebin, you've only dealt with my very first point.  Respond to everything else.

Comment: I can´t tell you what the directory structure is since I don´t know what that means, or more clearly I dont know how to explain? What´s not happening is that I can´t reach any of the classes that the twitter4j library provides. They can´t be resolved.

Comment: Update your posting with the exact console output that shows your build running and the error messages. Paste the output into a text editor and indent it all 4 spaces, and then paste the result into the "Code Sample" block in SO.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this kind of issue few weeks back when i try to utilize `Twitter4j` library through Gradle.

What i did was,

1. Downloaded the `Twitter4J` zip file from their site.
2. Open the extracted folder and there you will find `lib` folder. Open it.
3. You will find some `.lib` files like `twitter4j-core-4.0.3.jar`. This file `core` is important and you need to add remaining `.jars` when you use that application. If you're not sure, then copy all `.jars` and paste it in `libs` folder.

[image]

4. Then click File -> Project Structure -> Select app in the left column -> choose Dependency Tab.
5. Click `+` in right top and choose `File Dependency` then select the jars in libs folder.

[image]
6. Click Ok and you're done.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

Even I faced the similar problem recently and adding it like this to the gradle dependencies seems to work for me:

```
compile group: 'org.twitter4j', name: 'twitter4j-core', version: '4.0.7'
```